# Difference between random number and random variant?

Tags: random-variables

After generating random number we can get the random variant by using inverse transform or other techniques. What is the difference between random number and random variant. Can anyone explain it with an example or a graph.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "generating random number"? Usually a programming language allows generating a **uniform** pseudo-random number in a specific range. So clearly if you want some other distribution you need to use some method, the simplest of which is to use the inverse of the cumulative density function as you have mentioned. By the way, a "random variable" is not called a "random variant".